# How do I get my Python file to print in the terminal instead of in the server it sets up?

Tags: javascript, python, server, terminal

I am running a bit of a complicated setup where several files interact with each other:

- a python file, setting up a server, which is used to connect two users online
- a combination of js and html files to set up the web page that each user interacts with

So each user interacts with the js files, which in turn send a message to the python file, which reacts by sending the appropriate response to the js files on the other user’s end, etc.

To launch all this, I simply open the python file in my terminal — thus opening up the websockets — and then I type in the address of my html file on my browser. I know the functions in my python file are executing correctly because the interaction does work on my browser, however, none of the prints in the functions show up on my terminal…

So for example, in the python file:

```py
def message_received(client, server, message):
  print("Client(%d) said: %s" % (client['id'], message))
  response = json.loads(message)
  response_code = response['response_type']
  handle_client_response(client['id'], response_code, response)# another function defined elsewhere

PORT = 9004

print('starting up')
server = WebsocketServer(PORT, '0.0.0.0')# this is calling the actual server set up from another file, which I didn 't write myself.
server.set_fn_message_received(message_received)
server.run_forever()
```

The "starting up" is the only thing that will actually print, the print in message_received doesn't show up, even though I know for a fact the function is working because handle_client_response is called correctly.

My guess is this is because the function are not actually executed on the terminal, but on the server that I set up, so python is trying to print in the server instead of the terminal. But also I have no idea what I’m talking about — first time I ever do this type of complicated files interaction so I’m very confused!

Am I guessing the problem correctly? Any fix for it?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code or a working sample of how your program is working, then we can help you troubleshoot the issue. We can only guess what the problem could be with the current information.

Comment: Because I am dealing with such huge chunks of code and I can't really pinpoint the problem to a single paragraph, it's a bit hard to provide a sample that's both clear and concise... but I'll try!

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe using a library like logging to handle the print of messages. That way, you can specify where the log messages should be written to.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def message_received(client, server, message):
    logging.debug("Client(%d) said: %s" % (client['id'], message))
    response = json.loads(message)
    response_code = response['response_type']
    handle_client_response(client['id'], response_code, response)
```

Hopefully this will fix it.

Comment: It didn't work as is, or in a log file, but I'm trying to read through a bit more of the documentation on that library to figure out if it can solve my problem. Thanks for the suggestion!